# How does RealTerm send Numbers

Tags: putty, serial-port

How does RealTerm send numbers? For some reason, when I enter a number under the "Send" tab to be sent over the serial line in RealTerm, it works, but inputting the same commands in PuTTY through the command line does not work. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `Send Numbers` button after typing a decimal number (or several or they could be hexadecimal, etc.), it's sending the character that corresponds to that code. In PuTTY, if you want to send an ASCII 65 (decimal) then you'd type an "A". If you want to send an ASCII 11 (decimal - Vertical Tab) you could press Ctrl-K or hold down the Alt key and type 11 on the numeric keypad.

Without knowing what you're communicating with, what it expects for input, whether you have PuTTY configured properly, etc., that's the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to communicate with an iRobot series 500 Roomba. I am not quite sure what it expects and trying to figure that out. The [iRobot SCI documentation](http://www.roombadevtools.com/docs_roombasci.pdf) lists opcodes which can be sent to the Roomba to control it. Right now, I am trying to send the two opcodes 128 and 133 to the Roomba. In Realterm, all I have done is go to the "Send Numbers" button. In PuTTY, I have tried communicating with the serial port using the same baud & other config + forcing local echo and line editing on, to no avail. Can you help?

Comment: @tushark: I'm not familiar with communicating with or controlling a Roomba. Are those opcodes decimal byte values or ASCII digit characters? It seems like they are the former. If you hold down Alt and press 128 on the numeric keypad and release Alt do you get any response? Is the Roomba showing any startup output (copyright message, prompt string, etc.) when you use PuTTY? Since RealTerm works, why not continue using it?

Comment: @tushark: Now that I've had a chance to glance at the docs, I see that they are byte values so there's a good chance that the Alt key technique will work. By the way, I don't see an opcode 133 documented.

Comment: @dennis-williamson I am trying to figure out the data type that I need to send to the Roomba and don't have a numeric keypad. I was using PuTTY / RealTerm to debug and need to figure out how to send the opcodes because I'm writing a program in PHP for the Roomba. Someone wrote a [PHP serial class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html), so I can communicate with the Roomba, but the Roomba doesn't seem to be accepting any of my commands. [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998847/php-roomba-serial-port-communication)

Comment: @dennis-williamson Thanks for looking at the docs. Is there another method which doesn't use a numeric keypad? The 133 opcode is for powering the Roomba on and off. Thanks for the help once again!

Comment: @tushark: Are you using a laptop? Does it have a Fn-key overlaid numeric keypad? Fn-Alt-j would be a one, Fn-Alt-u would be a four. Otherwise you could use the Windows Character Map and paste characters from it to PuTTY. A 128 would be a hex 80. The character you see would depend on the font (but wouldn't affect what the Roomba sees). You said RealTerm works. Why don't you stick with it? The docs indicate that the Roomba could appear to hang if it's expecting data bytes that it hasn't received after an opcode that requires them. I'm assuming you've cycled power manually to start fresh.

Comment: @dennis-williamson I am using a laptop, but it doesn't have an overlaid numeric keypad. I tried the Windows character map, but unfortunately, selecting the numbers there and pasting it in doesn't work (it just shows numbers for the characters). I don't really want to use either PuTTY or RealTerm - I'm trying to figure out how to convert to the necessary data type in PHP (StackOverflow question referenced above). In doing so, I decided to try and get it to work in PuTTY and now I would like to figure that out before programming even further. Thanks for the repeated help!

Comment: @tushark: Never mind regarding Char Map. I just did some testing and it wants to deal with everything in Unicode. You wouldn't select the digits there, by the way. If it worked you'd select the character that corresponded to the byte value (it would be something like "Ç"). Here's how you can output a decimal 128 byte in PHP from the command line using the hex equivalent: `php -r 'print "\x80";'`. You should be able to do something similar to send that byte over the serial line using the serial class you mentioned.

Comment: @tushark: By the way, you can also do the output in decimal like this: `php -r 'print chr(128);'` or `php -r 'printf("%c",128);'`.

Comment: @dennis-williamson Thanks! What is the php -r for? Do you mean to only insert the code in single quotes? I have tried $serial->sendMessage("\x80"), $serial->sendMessage(chr(128)), and $serial->sendMessage("%c",128). The first two run, but don't work. The third one hangs during execution for some reason. Any ideas? Thanks for your repeated help!

Comment: @tushark: It allows you to run short code snippets from the command line without needing `<?...?>`. I don't know why the first two variations you tried didn't work, but the last one isn't likely to. The way you'd probably need to do that might be something like `$char = sprintf("%c",128); $serial->sendMessage($char);`. All three are essentially the same. (The `sendMessage()` function takes an optional wait time as a second parameter, so your third form seems to hang because you told it to wait for 128 seconds.) If these aren't working then the communication parameters aren't set correctly...

Comment: ... or there's something wrong. Does it work properly using RealTerm?

Comment: @dennis-williamson I have tried everything and it still doesn't work. I don't know how to get PHP to work in the command line, but that doesn't seem to work for me. However, PHP does run off my webserver, which my Roomba is connected to through serial line. The goal is not to use RealTerm at all - it was just a method of testing whether the Roomba was responding to commands. Rather, it is to output through PHP the given values. I'm guessing this might have something to do with how the serial class for PHP is sending the data? Also, is PHP even capable of what I am asking?

Comment: @tushark: I would think PHP should be capable of doing this. Unfortunately serial communication is sometimes a nightmare to deal with. Assuming that RealTerm is actually working and making your Roomba perform actions (I'm still not 100% sure since you haven't directly answered my question(s) regarding that), then there's no reason it shouldn't be possible. I've only written stuff for the web using PHP and I'm very rusty even on that so I have no idea whether the CGI version of PHP can do what you want. When you call `$serial->deviceOpen()` what mode are you using for its argument? It should...

Comment: ...be `r+b` or `rb` or omitted (to use the default which is `r+b`).

Comment: Are you connecting using a USB to serial adapter which has lights on it? If so, do the lights change when you try to communicate with the Roomba? If it's a regular serial cable can you buy or borrow a serial breakout box with status lights (similar to [this](http://www.bb-elec.com/product.asp?sku=BREAK-1) )?

Comment: @dennis-williamson I am out of the house right now, but I wanted to thank you for your help and answer a few of your questions. I am already using a USB to serial adapter with lights on it (which is how I know I am communicating with the Roomba - it lights up in the direction of sending information to the Roomba). Using RealTerm, I can communicate with the Roomba directly using the Send Numbers function (if I try to communicate any other way, it sends every keypress). Also, I call $serial->deviceOpen(); just like that? Should I be sending an argument? Thanks for the help once again!

Comment: @tushark: Without an argument, it uses the default of `r+b` which is suitable for your use. Maybe you could edit your question and post your code and I could look at it.

Comment: @dennis-williamson Would it be more appropriate to edit my [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998847/php-roomba-serial-port-communication) since this is now programming related? I'll post code as soon as I get back. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @tushark: Probably so, please leave a reply here when you do so I get the notification. By the way, only the first three characters are needed so you can say `@Dennis` instead of using my whole name.

Comment: @Dennis I added the code to the [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998847/php-roomba-serial-port-communication) question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

### Experiment

#### (RealTerm -> RealTerm)

I connected 2 serial cables to each other and ran 2 instances of RealTerm to observe the difference.

(Note output was set to Display As Hex(space), and EOL turned off)

**Send Numbers**: Only works if the entire string consists exclusively of digits 0-9 or is prefixed with `0x` (hex)
**Send Ascii:** Converts each character to an ascii character before sending

| Value | Send Numbers | Send Ascii |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `AA` | N/A | `41 41` |
| `123` | `7B` | `31 32 33` |
| `0xAA` | `AA` | `30 78 41 41` |
| `9` | `09` | `39` |
| `00` | `00` | `30 30` |
| (space) | N/A | `20` |
| `0x03` | `03` | `30 78 30 33` |

#### (Putty -> RealTerm)

I rean the experiment with 1 putty window sending output to a RealTerm window.

(Note: Force local echo was turned on)

Putty behaves exactly like RealTerm `Send Ascii` button

| Value | Putty |
| --- | --- |
| `AA` | `41 41` |
| `123` | `31 32 33` |

---

#### Summary

Putty is only able to send ASCII. Other emulators such as RealTerm and [Tera Term](https://serverfault.com/a/405438/169180) are able to send data as binary or decimal values.